# Unpack boot.img and add "androidboot.selinux=enforcing" to boot.img-cmdline not work on Samsung

Tags: samsung, lineageos, selinux, heimdall

After flashing Android 13 of LineageOS to Galaxy Note 10+, I'm trying to set SELinux permissive following the steps.

1. Unpack `boot.img` and add `androidboot.selinux=permissive` to `boot.img-cmdline`
2. use Heimdall, and flash the packed boot.img:
   `heimdall flash --BOOT myboot.img`

The phone would auto-reboot after the flashing was complete. But `adb getprop ro.boot.selinux` still returns `enforcing`.
And I checked `cat /proc/cmdline`, there is `androidboot.selinux=enforce`.

This method works on Pixel 3XL with Android 13 LineageOS. I don't know why flash boot.img does not work on Galaxy Note 10+.

I checked boot.img with hex editor(vim), and found cmdline as there.

```
00000000: 414e 4452 4f49 4421 10e0 f602 0080 0010  ANDROID!........
00000010: 96d5 1500 0000 0011 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000020: 0001 0010 0008 0000 0100 0000 8301 001a  ................
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000040: 616e 6472 6f69 6462 6f6f 742e 7365 6c69  androidboot.seli
00000050: 6e75 783d 7065 726d 6973 7369 7665 2062  nux=permissive b
00000060: 7569 6c64 7661 7269 616e 743d 7573 6572  uildvariant=user
00000070: 6465 6275 6700 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  debug...........
```

Comment: your mistake is you can't set selinux permissive on stock kernel. compile custom kernel with CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_DEVELOP